# malloc double free behaviour

Tags: c, linux, unix, malloc, gnu

The GNU manual page for `malloc` defines that when `free()` called twice with the same pointer (that was previously allocated by `malloc()`) "undefined behaviour occurs".

What kind of behaviour is that?
Where can I find more Information about this kind of error?

Comment: It means your program could start [launching games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) instead of doing what you thought you coded your program to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Undefined behavior" simply means that the implementation isn't required to deal with the situation in any particular way; *any* behavior or result is considered "correct".

The result of `free`-ing a pointer more than once is up to the underlying implementation of `malloc`; the result could be a crash and core dump, or it could corrupt the `malloc` arena (fouling up future allocations/deallocations), or it could ignore the double `free` entirely.

Answer (score 7):

The C99 standard states the following for *undefined behaviour* (under the *Terms and definitions* section):

> Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

In summary: *anything can happen*. The worst case is for the program to behave as expected.

Comment: "The worst case is for the program to behave as expected."  Golden :)

Answer (score 1):

you can not free twice the same pointer at the same time.

If you want to do a such behaviour without undefined behaviour.

you can use the following macro instead of the all free of your code

```
#define FREE(X) free(X); X=NULL


char *p;
p=malloc(50);
FREE(p);
FREE(p);
```

When you force the pointer to be `NULL`, this will avoid the undefined behaviour in the next free. Because `free(NULL)` do not cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: for the downvoter the free(null) will not cause undefined behaviour

Comment: You probably attracted a downvote because you didn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: In fact I suggested an alternate solution for the user in cass if his programs contains  2 free and he wants to keep them for some reason.

Comment: I know. I'm just pointing out that you did not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen. One of the possible outcomes is that your program runs perfectly. Another possible outcome is that your program crashes. Or indeed anything else that you can think of.

You won't gain any insight trying to analyse particular instance of undefined behaviour. The remedy is not to call `free()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

"undefined behavior" generally means your program will crash. For implementors of the c library it means they can handle that case however they want. They would be free for example to ignore your second invalid free. Almost no c libraries will do this.  Most c libs will just abort your program with some kind of memory violation error.

Comment: "undefined behavior generally means your program will crash." No, that's not what it means at all.