# Changing gcc/g++ version causes segfault

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc

It seems that changing the version of gcc I use from `gcc 4.7.3` to `gcc 4.9.2` causes a segfault for my project (after a clean build and run).

In an unfortunate turn of events `gdb` is broken on the server I am 
getting this error on and can't use it for now. Any known changes in gcc itself that could cause this? I suspect the issue is potentially caused by a double free.

Comment: Have you tried `valgrind`?

Comment: Most likely, there is some UB in your code, like the guessed one, double free. It is almost impossible to conclude anything without seeing the code.

Comment: In summary the diff that is causing this adds a pointer member to a class. The pointer is set but _never_ used.  This seems like a very strange thing to cause a segfault, so I assumed that perhaps gcc is trying to generate a destructor for that object calling free on the pointer. Is this possible? Is there a change in the way destructors are being generated between 4.7 and 4.9?

Comment: Consider also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177457/debug-heap-stl-debugging-equivalent-for-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use valgrind.

Valgrind is a debugging tool only requiring for your code to be compiled with the -g flag. It's the best way to spot segmentation fault over a program, or any memory leak.

Think about using valgrind options while debugging (it's at the bottom of the valgrind report) something like leak-checkfull (I'm not able to run valgrind right now so I can't tell you exactly what it is).

But whenever I compile my code, I use valgrind with it to check every possible failure. Consider even putting VG in your Makefile rules for more simplicity.

Comment: Ok, thanks, using valgrind helped me find the source of the double free, which is an undefined behaviour as suggested above. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685240/malloc-double-free-behaviour