# C code that uses blas, lapack and openmp working with gcc 4.9 but gives run time error with gcc 6

Tags: runtime-error, lapack, blas, gcc4.9, gcc6

I have written a code in C.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/RobeDM/LIBIRWLS).

It makes use of the libraries blas, lapack and openmp.

I have compiled the blas and lapack libraries following [these instrucions](https://pheiter.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/howto-installing-lapack-and-blas-on-mac-os/).

I use these flags to tell the compiler the libraries that it should link: `-lblas -llapack -fopenmp`.

I was using `gcc 4.9` and the program can run correctly.

Recently I have updated gcc to gcc 6 and it shows many warning msgs about the implicit declaration of the blas and lapack functions:

```
src/PSIRWLS-train.c:152:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'dgemm_' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 dgemm_(&trans, &trans, &(dataset.l), &ncols, &size,&factorA, KSC, &(dataset.l), miZ, &size, &factor, miKSM, &(dataset.l));
```

And when I run the app a segmentation fault error appears.

I am completely lost about the differences of gcc 4.9 and gcc 6, do you know any explanation about this?

Comment: The link to your code leads to error 404... You may be interested by [cblas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_cblas) and [Lapacke](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) which are the C interfaces to BLAS / LAPACK. Otherwise, you may have to decleare [`extern dgemm_(...)`](http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/10/31_cblas_clapack_lapacke/) . Notice that declaring fortran functions this way may lead to portability problems, because the naming convention changes between Linux and the W-thing... Using Cblas and Lapacke leaves this issue  (and some others) to the developers of these interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

1 - Some default flags are different in gcc 4 and 6. gcc 6 shows warnings when you don't decleare blas and lapack functions this way:

extern void dgemm_(...)

2 - It scaped me the initialization of one variable that had to be initialized to 0.
 I coded  int i,j = 0;
 when I had to code int i=0, j=0;

gcc 4 initialized i to 0 (and the program was running correctly) and gcc 6 didn't (creating a segmentation fault because these variables were to index)

Answer (score 0):

I had [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918238/changing-gcc-g-version-causes-segfault) once, and it seems very likely that there is some undefined behaviour in your code (e.g. a double free), which is handled in a compiler specific manner. Perhaps this changed between gcc 4.9 and 6.0.

It's hard to say without knowing your code, but you can use a number of tools yourself to track this issue down, for example [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) or especially [valgrind's memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) (worked brilliantly for me):

```
valgrind --tool memcheck <your binary here>
```

This will report locations of memory related errors and undefined behaviours in your code.